# Bootstrap Carousel Controls

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm working with the Carousel within bootstrap. I have tested this with many different variations. Even when I copy and paste the example code from bootstrap it still does not work. I have verified that the file paths are accurate. The controls still appear but they do not seemed to be linked to anything. I've seen a few places that mention a "function" but when I add this in nothing changes.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="myCarousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="pics/01.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    This should be first picture
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <img src="pics/02.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    This should be another picture

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="pics/03.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    This is the last picture
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="icon-prev"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
            <span class="icon-next"></span>
        </a>
    </div>



</div>
```

This is my code relevant to the carousel and I have below that these two js script calls

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I'm sure that its something simple but I cannot find what is wrong with this.

Comment: Try linking to jQuery & Bootstrap JS before your HTML up in the `<head>` tag instead? Sometimes you do want JS last, but not when it's required for your entire page structure & functionality. If the DOM has already loaded, the event handlers might not work. Any errors in your developer console?

Comment: Between your suggestion and the other answers I have solved the problem. Thank you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the id of carousel but you didn't update any of the controls referencing that id. Your `carousel-indicators` and `carousel-control` need to reference "myCarousel-example-generic" not "carousel-example-generic".

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
        <div id="myCarousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
    
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150?text=1" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        This should be first picture
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150?text=2" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        This should be another picture
    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/750x150?text=3" style="max-width: 100%;" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        This is the last picture
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="icon-prev"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                <span class="icon-next"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    
    
    
    </div>
```

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested. I think this was left over from a few copy and paste I did troubleshooting. However after making the changes I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: @TheJakeMoony - I'm unable to duplicate your issue using the code in my answer. I've just updated my answer to a runnable snippet so you can see it working. Is it possible something else in your page is breaking it?

Comment: I'm not sure why but it now works after coping and pasting your snippet. Thank you so much :D sorry for the n00b question.